# Can't connect to web-server on local host behind NAT

Tags: ubuntu, networking, port-forwarding

I got Ubuntu as host. I'm running a web-server on `http://192.168.199.8:80`. It is accessible from the local network, but when I'm trying to reach it by external IP, I go to my router's web-page.

I arranged port forwarding on router for port 80 to my local IP 192.168.199.8.

Unfortunately web-server is still unavailable via external IP.

I checked whether the port is open via http://www.canyouseeme.org/. As it showed that the port is unavailable, I changed port used to 3659 (not forget to rearrange port forwarding rule). Although http://www.canyouseeme.org/ shows that port 3659 is open, I still can't reach my web-server.

Where can the problem be?

Comment: I'ld suggest doing a Network trace for example with wireshark. What is the browser saying when you connect to your webserver? Does "telnet <your server> 3659" get a connect?

Comment: browser is trying to connect and does not provide any response, it just does not stop trying, curl does that as well. do you mean i should do traceroute?

Comment: traceroute will not help. As I said: I'ld suggest doing a Network trace for example with wireshark. Does "telnet <your server> 3659" get a connect?

Comment: ??? So you get a black window with no Output after starting Telnet? This is good, because this means that you can connect to the web Server. Please check your webserver logs, maybe do a Network trace with wireshark at the web Server and check Peters answer.

Comment: here is the result of telnet: telnet ***.***.***.212 3659
Trying ***.***.***.212...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

Comment: @Werner Henze, sorry, started editing comment and finished playing with setting for an hour. i still can't connect

Comment: Then your port forwarding is not working or you are connecting to the wrong IP/port.

Comment: the ip is ok, 'cause if i turn off port forwarding, i can reach my router's admin panel via external ip. once i even managed to connect by other computer using 8080 port via browser. i'll follow your advice no use wireshark, as soon as i have time, could you please advise, what should i test first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be in the config of the web server if its only allowing headers with the internal ip address. It may only allow the header in form "htp://192.168.199.8" but you may need to allow the external IP as well.

Comment: thank you, i'll have a look into server's config. the point is, that at first i was trying to reach apache, but after that while playing with ports and port-forwarding i was using SimpleHTTPServer from python's package, 'cause it's faster to restart.